# How to make form not refresh with custom submit button in React

Tags: reactjs

im using react and i try to make form with custom submit button (with div)
but when i submit the form the page automatically refreshes, despite `e.preventDefault`
my code :

```
 <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()} className="form">
        <div
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(".form").submit();
          }}
          id="button"
        >
          Submit
        </div>
      </form>
```

demo on code sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-pond-9fcnr

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `button`?

Comment: for better styling

Comment: @frannoo_ — Use a div introduces **massive** accessibility problems. Style the button instead.

Comment: Not to mention this issue would have never occurred if a button were used.... This error is due to how you are submitting the form (essentially, the *interactive* `submit` event is bypassed)... You do know you can style buttons, too, right?

Answer (score 3):

As per the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#dom-form-submit-dev)

> `form . submit()`
>
> Submits the form, bypassing **interactive constraint** validation and **without firing a submit event**.

This is why your `onSubmit` callback doesn't get called, and page is getting refreshed as per the normal browser behaviour.

I'd suggest a work around in this case:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";


function App() {
  const submitEl = useRef(null);
  const handleFormSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const handleBtnClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitEl.current.click();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleFormSubmit} className="form">
        <div onClick={handleBtnClick} id="button">
          Submit
        </div>
        <input
          ref={submitEl}
          name="submit"
          type="submit"
          style={{ display: "none" }}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I use this solution for react-hook-form.
I needed to bind custom submit function (handleSubmit) to pagination and it works out well. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution but I don't know if it is the best idea:

```
  <form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault()} >
        <div
          onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.querySelector(".hidden-button").click();
          }}
          id="button"
        >
          Submit
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="hidden-button"/>
      </form>
```

and also in css :

```
#hidden-button{
      display: none;
    }
```

Comment: You should really be using `refs` for this.. It is bad practices, and an anti-pattern, to directly interact with the DOM like this.. It can cause some odd things to happen (read more into the issues Discord just had due to directly interacting with the DOM).. [More here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)